# Does this particular solution to a linear ode with varying coefficient vanish for all t and is it transferable to matrices?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that a particular initial value solution to the following differential equation is zero for all $t$.
The differential equation is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(t) = g(t)f(t)
$$
and the initial condition is $f(t_0) = 0$. I conclude that in this case the first derivative and thus  all higher order derivatives are zero at $t_0$. Since all time derivatives of higher order vanish and the initial value is zero, the particular solution to this problem is $f(t)=0 \ \forall \ t$.

All higher order derivatives can be factorized into a form where $f(t)$ appears as multiplicative factor by plugging in the one order lower derivative.

$$\begin{aligned}
f^{(n)} &= g^{(n-1)}f^{(0)} + g^{(n-2)}f^{(n-1)} \ \forall \ n>1 \\
f^{(1)} &= g^{(0)}f^{(0)} \\
f^{(0)}(t_0) = 0  &\Rightarrow  f^{(n)}(t_0) = 0 \\
f_{particular}(t) &= 0
\end{aligned}$$
with $$f^{(n)} = \frac{d^n f}{d t^n} $$

Is this correct or am i missing something ?

Assuming that this is correct, is it transferable to matrix equations where $f$ and $g$ are matrices ?

EDIT:

In 1 dimension the solution can be given as
$$
f(t) = f(t_0)\exp\left(\int^t_{t_0}d\tau g(\tau)\right)
$$
which shows that $f(t)$ vanishes for $f(t_0)=0$. Is there a solution of similar  form, when going to a matrix differential equation $f\rightarrow F, g\rightarrow G$ of the form,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}F(t) = G(t) F(t)
$$
where $G(t)$ does not commute with its integral $\int d\tau G(\tau)$. Can the solution still be brought into something of the form
$$
F(t) = F(t_0) \cdot (\dots)
$$
?

I didn't manage to do derive such a form for a non commuting matrix $G(t)$ but i think my argument for $f$ should also hold for matrices. I guess i need to include the assumption that the derivatives of $G$ exist.

Is my argument then valid for matrices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments use the fact that $g$ has derivatives of all orders. But this is not neccesary.

If we only assume that $g$ is continuous, then $g$ has an anti-derivative $G$. The general solution of the linear first order differential equation

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t) = g(t)f(t)$$

is given by

$$f(t)=C e^{G(t)}, $$

where $C \in \mathbb R.$ If $f(t_0)=0$, then $Ce^{G(t_0)}=0,$, hence $C=0.$

This gives $f(t)=0 \ \forall \ t.$

Comment: I didn't want to use this since i need to apply the result to matrices. The matrix corresponding to $g(t)$ does not necessarily commute with itself for all $t$. This is the reason why i tried to find another "proof", which can be applied easily to matrices. But i think i can make the assumption that g(t) has derivatives of all orders. But my argument isn't wrong or is it ?